# Could not Install the latest version of Yeoman and the Yeoman generator for Office Add-ins globally

Tags: node.js, onenote

I am trying to Install the latest version of Yeoman and the Yeoman generator for Office Add-ins globally.I run the following code on my macbook terminal.

```
npm install -g yo generator-office
```

It gives me an error message list throughout the terminal.

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got permission issues. If you type `ls -l /usr/local/lib/` in the terminal you will see you don't have **write** permissions to that folder (see [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-permissions) for more basic info on permissions). [beware of installing global packages though](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/issue-with-global-node-npm-packages/).

As proposed by [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions), use [node version manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (nvm). Follow their installation instructions [step by step](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installation) and you won't have permission issues. `node` and the global packages you install will then be placed in a hidden directory `/home/YOUR_USER_NAME/.nvm` where you have full permissions.